# C++ Write Registry

Tags: c++, windows, registry, key

I will write this registry key in the registry.
It should be written in C++ for windows 7 and 8.
This is the .reg file:

```
REGEDIT4
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bin\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\binimage\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Bootvis Trace File\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Crestron SIMPL Windows Compiled Program\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\elby.VCDMount.1\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\gBurner\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ImgBurn.AssocFile.bin\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IsoBuster.bin\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\IZArcBIN\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MPlayerFileVideo\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PAISO\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\StuffIt.Archive.Open.Generic\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\StuffIt11.Archive.Open.Generic\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\TzBIN\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\UltraEdit.bin\]
[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VLC.bin\]

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bin\]
@="exefile"
"Content Type"="application/x-msdownload"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bin\PersistentHandler\]
@="{098f2470-bae0-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.bin\shell\open\command\]
@="\"%1\" %*"
```

IDK how to do it but maybe anyone here can help me :)
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the WinAPI functions for registry handling. You can find the list [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

I would be checking these functions:

```
RegCreateKeyEx
RegOpenKeyEx
RegGetValue
RegSetValueEx
RegCloseKey
```